# How to break a div in 2 lines when it would overflow the parent in HTML?

Tags: html, css, gridview

I have some `div`s in a row with a grid system. When the screen is too small to display them, they should break in a new line. How can I achieve this?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
It should break depending on the screen size. So, when the screen has just a width of 250px, a single block should be in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jjgmxe51/1/)

try this:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, that works. But I forgot to mention that it should break depending on the screen size. So, when the screen has just a width of 250px, a single block should be in a row.

Comment: @chocolatecake not possible in this display-grid css, using bootstrap

Comment: @chocolatecake https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/